# XSLT string parsing

Tags: xslt, string

Im new to XSLT for the 'PrimarySubject' below I need to replace'&' characters to %26 and ' ' characters to %20 that it contains.

```
<xsl:template name="BuildLink"> 
    <xsl:param name="PrimarySubject" /> 
    <xsl:text>?PrimarySubject=</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$PrimarySubject" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

Is there string replace function I can use in xslt version 1 ?
Thanks,

Comment: Ah, I see, you try my suggestion to implement an URI encoder in XSLT ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This can be done most easily using the [FXSL Library](http://fxsl.sf.net)**, more exactly its **`str-map`** template.

**Here is a simple example**.

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:testmap="testmap"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl testmap"
>
   <xsl:import href="str-map.xsl"/>

   <!-- to be applied on any xml source -->

   <testmap:testmap/>

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vTestMap" select="document('')/*/testmap:*[1]"/>
     <xsl:call-template name="str-map">
       <xsl:with-param name="pFun" select="$vTestMap"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="'abc&amp;d f'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="testmap:*">
      <xsl:param name="arg1"/>

      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$arg1 = '&amp;'">%26</xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$arg1 = ' '">%20</xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$arg1"/></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used), produces the wanted result:**

`abc%26d%20f`

Comment: Better to use a library someone else has written, save a bit of time in the "I didn't think of that situation".

Comment: @Nat, Of course, users of FXSL rarely, if at all, need to implement recursion themselves.

Comment: @infant-programmer Nice to see you, what is the meaning of "[15 chars]"in your comment?

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question is how would i pass the value of vTestMap as a parameter to another template? I tried below but it doesnt work...
<xsl:call-template name="BuildLink">
<xsl:with-param name="PrimarySubject" select="$vTestMap" />
</xsl:call-template>

Comment: @nav the code in my answer passes $vTestMap as parameter already... There must be a problem in your code, but without seeing the code it's impossible to guess (for me, at least) what is wronf.

Comment: Sorry your code did work. It was just nuances of working with sharepoint that I couldnt use this solution. Due to errors with import statement, otherwise this would have worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

There are [several substring](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/W3C/xpath.html#function-substring-before) functions in XSLT:

- string substring-before(string, string)
- string substring-after(string, string)
- string substring(string, number, number?)